# Objective C syntax query

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, cocoa-touch

Apologies or asking what is probably a very straightforward question, but I'm new to C-Syntax languages in general and have found something that confused me.

I've see a couple of example bits of code that create a CGFloat object and then seem to treat them as a implicit array of some kind, for example.

```
CGFloat newFloat[3] = {value1,value2,value};
```

Is this a generally valid concept in objective C to create arrays, or is it something built into CGFloat to hand 3D points in space?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long term if you invest a little time now in reading a decent introductory book on Objective-C

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm in the middle of two of them, I just wasn't sure if I was interpreting this correctly.

Comment: Good luck - make sure the Objective-C books cover all the C basics and if not you might also want to supplement your reading with a decent C book too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called array initialisation and is a part of the language.

The `{value1,value2,value}` part is called an initialiser and can be used on the right side of the assignment whenever defining an array. When the number of elements in the initialiser corresponds to the specified size of the array, you don't actually need to explicitly specify the size:

```
CGFloat newFloat[] = {value1, value2, value};
```

This makes the maintenance easier since adding a new element at the end doesn't force you to update the size as well.

Such initialisers are supported for structs as well.

Comment: You should also have mentioned the array size is optional when initializer list is given.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an implicit array, the left hand side explicitly declares a variable that is a CGFloat array of length 3. The syntax is actually part of the C standard.